# my log.info(...) in GSP just does not come out in my log files, why ? It just took so long to figure out. Is there a better way?

Tags: grails, groovy, log4j, gsp

**Recently I wasted a stupendous amount of time when I had a GSP page crashing for a user.**

Essentially `request.user.currRole().name` was crashing within the GSP page. `.user` was null. Not sure why, still figuring that out hence, I decided to do some logging.

So, I turned on logging by the doing the following ...

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.log4j.*" %>
<%
 
    final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
%>
```

Then somewhere further down my page I had the following line to tell me if the value was null or not

```
<% log.info(" request.user=${request.user}"); %>
```

For these logs to come out I amended my `Config.groovy` like so, after spending ages going thru countless of grails documentation & stackoverflow posts

```
            info 'grails.app','org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages'
```

I assumed that somehow my GSP hung in a sub-tree package within the roots exposed in `info` above.

I was perplexed and angry as to why the logs just did not come out.

Only realizing after a **long R&D stint** that, that Groovy Page gets pre-compiled into a class that does not hang from any of the package roots mentioned in Config.groovy (unlike JSPs where they get parsed and compiled classes at the Tomcat server end) and that class is called `gsp_motorSystem_motorDeptedit_gsp`

**It worked when I did the following ...**

```
            info 'grails.app','org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',
            'gsp_motorSystem_motorDeptedit_gsp'
```

Questions

1. Could there have been a better or a less time-consuming way (Grails & Groovy are supposed to alleviate the verbosity of Java but I find the brevity of Groovy makes the coder think far too much about what is really happening in the code and it thus becomes a maintainability nightmare anyways)
2. Was there a log object available in GSPs like there are in Grails Controllers & Service objects ?
3. Should I have used `final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("motordept.edit.gsp")` and then amended `Config.groovy` like so

```
info 'grails.app','org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',
            'motordept.edit.gsp'
```

4. Or is this my weak understanding of best practice for log4j usage in JSPs or GSPs in this case

Comment: `Logger.getLogger( 'my.gsps.one' )` is the most logical and fast way of creating your logger instance in a GSP. And yes, you should put your logging statements inside the controller or tagLib, as you have the very same objects there

Comment: Since GSP can use JSP tag libraries (cf. [documentation](https://gsp.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html#usingJSPTagLibraries)), you can use `log4j-taglib` (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.17.2/log4j-taglib/)) to add logging to your pages.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I guess this tag lib can only be used if one is using the log4j 2 api. Correct ? But, nonetheless, thanks, wasn't aware that JSP tag libs could be used directly in GSPs

Comment: @user1561783: yes, to use `log4j-taglib` you need Log4j2 API, but Log4j 1.2 has reached end-of-life 8 years ago, so you should consider migrating.